# Как сделать чередование рекламы?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как сделать чередование рекламы гугл адсенс и яндекс рся?
т.е. в шаблоне single.php нужно сделать, чтобы рекламные блоки адсенс и рся показывались 50/50, по очереди, если показывается адсенс, тогда не должен показываться рся, и также рся.

Comment: SeVlad, ты чего это в мою тему влез? Я ведь тебе раньше говорил про это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот такой вариант, с файлом-счётчиком:

```
function adv_router(){
  
    $counter_name = bloginfo('template_directory') . "adv_counter.txt";

    if(!$f = fopen($counter_name, "w")){
        fwrite($f,"0");
        fclose($f);
        exit();
    }
    $f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
    $counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
    $route = ++$counterVal % 2;
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f, $counterVal);
    fclose($f);

    if($route){
       echo // гугл;
    }else{
       echo // яндекс;
    }

}
```

## UPD:

вот такой вариант, с добавлением счётчика в таблицу options:

```
function adv_router(){

global $wpdb;

$counterVal = 0;

$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
// или $prefix = $wpdb->base_prefix; // читает префикс из wp_config.php

if(!get_option('adv_counter_01')){
    $wpdb->insert(
        $prefix . 'options',
        array( 'option_name' => 'adv_counter_01', 'option_value' => '0'),
        array( '%s', '%d' )
    ) 
}else{
    $counterVal = ++(get_option('adv_counter_01'));
    update_option( 'adv_counter_01', $counterVal));
   
}

if($counterVal % 2){
       echo // гугл;
    }else{
       echo // яндекс;
    }
}
```

Comment: а если нет прав на создание файла? есть ли попроще вариант?

Comment: к базе есть доступ? фтп?

Comment: Проще быть уже не может. Создайте файл не в корне, а в той папке, куда есть доступ.

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin, доступ по фтп

Comment: @word обновил ответ

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin, не пойму почему, но не получается поставить +1. При нажатии на стрелку, выдаёт такое сообщение http://clip2net.com/s/3N7oxb6. Благодарю

Comment: хз, ответ помог?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin, да, получилось благодаря вашему ответу что-то похожее на ответ ниже, данный KAGG Design :)

Comment: Ну, собссно, збс;)

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать некое хранилище счетчика - файл или базу данных. Самым быстрым способом будет использование опции WordPress.

```
$advert = get_option( 'advert', 0 ); // значение по умолчанию - 0, если опция не существует в базе.
if ( 0 === ( $advert % 2 ) ) {
    // остаток от деления на 2 = 0, показываем Google
} else {
    // остаток от деления на 2 = 1, показываем Yandex
}
$advert++; // увеличиваем счетчик
update_option( 'advert', $advert ); // сохраняем в базе
```

Answer (score 0):

Генерируем рандомное число 0 или 1. Далее проверяем. Если число 1 - показываем рекламу гугл, если 0 - показываем рекламу яндекс.

```
<?php
  $r = mt_rand(0,1);
  if($r) {
    // показываем рекламу гугл
  } else {
    // показываем рекламу яндекс
  }
?>
```

Comment: так в таком случае 50/50 ведь не получится. Это будет рандомный показ. Разница в показе может быть большая

Comment: если подойти к вопросу более основательно - нужно где-то хранить значение последней выведенной рекламы. При последующей загрузке страницы доставать это значение. Тут может подойти, например, база данных. Либо куки если достаточно 50/50 на уровне браузера.

Comment: делается как-то так: $advert = get_option('advert'); 
if($advert)?

Comment: покажите пожалуйста небольшой пример, как правильно доставать из бд, и как вычислять текущее значение

Comment: Грамотно послал

Comment: Ради одного бита заводить базу данных? Это плохо.

Comment: @Mrak это вопрос по WordPress, база данных там есть всегда.